# How to calculate angular momentum of two colliding bodies about their shared center of mass in 2D?

Tags: physics, mathematics, geometry, collision-resolution

[I'm following this guide to implementing collisions in 2D physics](https://www.euclideanspace.com/physics/dynamics/collision/twod/index.htm).

It shows this diagram, but I don't understand how to calculate the values of `Da` and `Db`.

> **Apply conservation of angular momentum**
> [image: Two rotating squares A and B collide]
>
> choose to measure all angular momentums around the common centre of mass (`Pm`).
>
> Because this is inelastic case I have assumed that, on collision, the two objects stick together instantly, held on these relative positions and rotating about their common centre of mass. I could not find a way to allow them to be fixed normal to the direction of impact but allow them to slide along the point of imact. (because both objects are rotating).
>
> before the collision angular momentum is the sum of the angular momentums due to spin + the sum of angular momentums due orbiting about `Pm`.
>
> ```
> Ia * Wa + Da * Ma Va + Ib * Wb + Db * Mb Vb
> ```
>
> after the collision the angular momentum about the same point is
>
> ```
> Wf ( Ma * (Pa-Pm)^2 + Ia +Mb * (Pb-Pm)^2 + Ib)
> ```
>
> By conservation of angular momentum these two are equal:
>
> ```
> Ia * Wa + Da * Ma Va + Ib * Wb + Db * Mb Vb = Wf ( Ma * (Ra-Rm)^2 + Ia +Mb * (Rb-Rm)^2 + Ib)
>
> Wf = (Ia * Wa + Da * Ma Va + Ib * Wb + Db * Mb Vb) /( Ma * (Ra-Rm)^2 + Ia +Mb * (Rb-Rm)^2 + Ib)
> ```
>
> where:
>
> ```
> Rm = common centre of mass = (Ra * Ma + Rb * Mb )/ (Ma + Mb)
>
> Rb - Rm = (Rb Ma + Rb Mb - Ra * Ma - Rb * Mb)/ (Ma + Mb) = (Rb - Ra) * Ma / (Ma + Mb)
>
> Ra - Rm = (Ra Ma + Ra Mb - Ra * Ma - Rb * Mb)/ (Ma + Mb) = (Ra - Rb) * Mb / (Ma + Mb)
> ```

How can I compute `Da` and `Db` as used in these formulas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can see in the diagram that \$D_a\$ is the component of the separation distance between \$\vec P_a\$ and \$\vec P_m\$, measured along the axis perpendicular to \$\vec V_a\$, and likewise for the \$b\$ versions.

So we could calculate \$D_a\$ with a little trigonometry. Let's define the "radius" vector of A's position offset from the shared center of mass as \$\vec r_a = \vec P_a - \vec P_m\$. We can think of this vector as the hypotenuse of a right triangle, with the "adjacent" side parallel to \$\vec V_a\$, and then \$D_a\$ is the length of the "opposite" side. That means \$D_a = ||r_a|| \sin \theta_a\$, where \$\theta_a\$ is the angle between \$\vec r_a\$ and \$\vec V_a\$.

But wait... once we multiply \$D_a\$ by \$|| V_a||\$, we'd have the product of the lengths of two vectors and the sine of the angle between them... that sounds a lot like a [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)! That means \$D_a M_a V_a\$ is just the usual expression for [angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum) of a mass around a point: \$\vec r \times \vec p\$, where \$\vec r\$ is the offset of the mass from the pivot point, and \$ \vec p\$ is the mass's linear momentum.

We can calculate this as though we had three dimensions for the cross product, then just clip out the z component as our scalar.

$$\begin{align}
&\vec r \times \vec p\\
&= (\vec P_a - \vec P_m) \times M_a \vec V_a\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}{P_a}_x - {P_m}_x\\{P_a}_y - {P_m}_y\\0\end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix}M_a {V_a}_x\\M_a {V_a}_y\\0\end{bmatrix}\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ ({P_a}_x - {P_m}_x) M_a{V_a}_y - ({P_a}_y - {P_m}_y) M_a{V_a}_x\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

So you can use that z component in place of the product \$D_a M_a ||V_a||\$:

$$\begin{align}
D_a M_a ||V_a|| &= ({P_a}_x - {P_m}_x) M_a{V_a}_y - ({P_a}_y - {P_m}_y) M_a{V_a}_x\\
D_a &= \frac{ ({P_a}_x - {P_m}_x) {V_a}_y - ({P_a}_y - {P_m}_y) {V_a}_x} {||V_a||}
\end{align}
$$

...and likewise for `Db`. The nice thing about calculating it this way is we don't need to explicitly compute the angle or use any trigonometric functions. We do need a square root to get the scalar speed in the denominator, but chances are you're using that elsewhere anyway.

Comment: thank you so much, you are my hero.